# Python: How to write typing.overload decorator for bool arguments by value

Tags: python, overloading, mypy, static-typing, pyright

The example code of what I am trying to ask is below.
None of the examples on the internet try to overload argument value as such.
One of the argument is a bool value and I want to overload a method based on the bool value rather than the usual, argument type.

```py
from typing import overload, Union

@overload
def myfunc(arg: bool = True)-> str: ...

@overload
def myfunc(arg: bool = False) -> int: ...

def myfunc(arg: bool) -> Union[int, str]:
  if arg:
    return "something"
  else:
    return 0
```

Is the overloading code in the above example code correct ?
Can you give an example/blog/source that mentions this kind of overloading, since I couldn't find anything in Python docs and [pep-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)

I found one probable way of doing it is with `typing.Literal` as used in [latest python docs (since python v3.8)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal)

```py
from typing import overload, Union, Literal

@overload
def myfunc(arg: Literal[True]) -> str: ...

@overload
def myfunc(arg: Literal[False]) -> int: ...

def myfunc(arg: bool) -> Union[int, str]:
  if arg:
    return "something"
  else:
    return 0
```

But I cannot move to python 3.8 just yet as I am working on production code that is still on python 3.6, soon upgrading to 3.7 at best.
Hence I am still looking for answers on how to achieve this in python 3.6

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Install the [typing-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) module which contains official backports of various typing constructs. Then, do:

```py
from typing import overload, Union

# typing_extensions defines Literal for Python 3.7 and earlier, but
# re-exports it from 'typing' for later versions of Python.
from typing_extensions import Literal

@overload
def myfunc(arg: Literal[True]) -> str: ...

@overload
def myfunc(arg: Literal[False]) -> int: ...

@overload
def myfunc(arg: bool) -> Union[str, int]: ...

def myfunc(arg: bool) -> Union[int, str]:
    if arg: return "something"
    else: return 0
```

See the first example in the [mypy docs on literal types](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/literal_types.html) for why I included the third overload on bool.

Comment: Thank You !!!
@erictraut answered this in pyright issue I created of the same [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/428#issuecomment-566158408)

"You're on the right track. You need to use Literal[True] and Literal[False]. You can work around the need for Python 3.8 by importing Literal from typing_extensions and placing the annotation in quotes. This will prevent the python interpreter from evaluating the type at runtime."

Answer (score 18):

Building off the correct [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59361700), `@overloading` for default (keyword) arguments can be achieved as follows:

```
from typing import overload, Union, Literal

@overload
def myfunc(arg: Literal[True] = True) -> str: ...

@overload
def myfunc(arg: Literal[False]) -> int: ...

def myfunc(arg: bool =  True) -> Union[int, str]:
    if arg: return "something"
    else: return 0
```

The first overload (with `Literal[True]`) is used for type-checking function calls `myfunc(True)` and `myfunc()`, while the second overload (with `Literal[False]`) is used for type-checking the function call `myfunc(False)`.

Comment: How does this improve upon the accepted answer?

Comment: This example shows how to type a function that supplies a default argument, which is not covered in the accepted answer. In particular, the pattern above enables typecheckers like mypy to perform type inference on a call to `myfunc` that is made without any arguments, e.g. `x = myfunc()`.

Comment: At first, I thought you didn't need the type annotations for the actual/non-overloaded function definition. But actually, you should include them, because otherwise you could get a type wrong in an overload and it wouldn't be able to tell - it would treat all args as `Any`. This doesn't seem to have been nailed down the way it ought to be - https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8867#issuecomment-767842357

Comment: Also: as mentioned in the other answer, a third overload with identical args & annotations to the actual function definition is needed. Hopefully this will be fixed soon https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6113

Comment: How would this work if the `arg` argument is preceded by another argument with a default. For example:
```python
def myfunc(some_arg: int = 0, arg: bool = True) -> int | str:
```
In that case, `mypy` will raise the error `non-default argument follows default argument  [syntax]` for the second overload definition since it doesn't specify a default. However, actually specifying the default as
```python
@overload
def myfunc(some_arg: int = 0, arg: Literal[False] = False) -> str: ...
```
will print `Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types  [misc]`

Comment: @Pankrates in that case you need to use three overloads:
1. `@overload def myfunc(int_arg: int = 0, as_str: Literal[True] = True) -> str: ...`, 2. 
`@overload def myfunc(int_arg: int = 0, *, as_str: Literal[False]) -> int: ...`, 3. `@overload def myfunc(int_arg: int, as_str: Literal[False]) -> int: ...`.